# Concurrency in Operating System

Tags: operating-systems, concurrency

I had the following question in an exam:

Which of the following best describes the concept of concurrency in an operating system?

Options:

1. The ability to execute multiple programs simultaneously.
2. The ability to perform multiple I/O operations concurrently.
3. The ability to execute multiple threads simultaneously
4. The ability to allocate memory efficiently

The answer is given as **3**(which is correct) but could option **1** be an answer as well?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, no. You could have an OS that can run one application at a time only. It would be much less useful, but possible.

Comment: Actual example: https://www.includeos.org/